# Definition of Generalized Gauss Map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I wonder to get a definition of generalized Gauss map just as the case of Euclidean spaces. Can anyone give me a definition of Gauss map for an immersed hyprsurface in a generic Riemannian manifold, at least for noncompact Riemannian manifolds with positive sectional curvature( which are diffeomorphic to Euclidean spaces by Gromoll-Meyer theorem). Maybe we should use the soul theorem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a short paragraph at the end of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map#Generalizations) of the Wikipedia article

Comment: In this generality, you will need the Gauss map to map a $k$-dimensional submanifold to the Grassmannian bundle of $k$-planes in the tangent space of the ambient manifold. That is, if $M\subset N$, then the Gauss map will map $\gamma\colon M\to G(k,TN)$, where the fiber of $G(k,TN)$ over $x\in N$ is $G(k,T_xN)$. Include orientations if you want.